# Box select in Object Mode selects too many things

Tags: objects, object-mode

When I box select in blender I dont expect the selection to go through objects.

For example here I only want to select the two walls to move them down, the walls behind are okay
[image]

however with box select, it selects everything in its path
[image]

Is there some toggle or setting to avoid this behavior? Or another method of making such selections?

I know I could left click and shift left click those two walls, but on bigger selections I wanna be able to select multiple things by dragging instead of clicking everything

Comment: That's how box select is supposed to work. - It selects everything within the dotted box!

Comment: I think it is weird I expecetd this kind of behavior when box selecting in wireframe/xray mode

Comment: If you are selecting only two objects, I think you can use use shift-left-click to select them.

Comment: This is a bad limitation of selection in Object Mode, IMO. But it is one. Upvote it on Right-Click-Select